# Event listener firing multiple times

Tags: events, ethers.js

In my Next.js project, in the `app.jsx` file, I've set up a websocket and listeners for our 4 events.

However, when one of these events fires, it logs in Discord 3 or more times and I can't seem to figure out why.

Maybe something in Next is loading this multiple times and attaching a listener to a socket multiple times? Any ideas here?

Thanks

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Socket connections
    const socket = new ethers.providers.AlchemyWebSocketProvider(1, process.env.ALCHEMY)
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT, ABI, socket)

    contract.on('Minted', (address, amount) => {
        const text = `${address} minted ${amount} NFTs!`
        logInSalesDiscord(text)
            .then((success) => console.log(success))
    });

    contract.on('PromoMinted', (mintedTo, amount) => {
        const text = `We minted ${amount} NFTs to ${mintedTo}`
        logInSalesDiscord(text)
        .then((success) => console.log(success))
    })

    contract.on('FundsWithdrawn', (amount) => {
        const text = `${ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount, 18)} ETH were withdrawn to our Gnosis Safe`
        logInEventsDiscord(text)
            .then((success) => console.log(success))
    })

    contract.on('FallbackHit', (whoSent, amount) => {
        const text = `The fallback function was sent ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount, 18)} by ${whoSent}`
        logInSalesDiscord(text)
            .then((success) => console.log(success))
    })
    // End sockets
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first remove all listeners during unmount,

```
  contract.on('FallbackHit', (whoSent, amount) => {
        const text = `The fallback function was sent ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount, 18)} by ${whoSent}`
        logInSalesDiscord(text)
            .then((success) => console.log(success))
    })
    return () => {
      contract.removeAllListeners();
    };
  }, []);
```

Second, prevent multiple rendering

Answer (score 0):

may you can use simple rpc provider rather sockets I was having same issue I resolved it by using rpc provider infura
and only call a single event in useffect hook you can make multiple hooks make sure state you are changing is mounted and rendering only through one useEffect

```
Provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_ID}`)
const Dog = new ethers.Contract(
          DogAdress,
          NFTDog.abi,
          Provider);

useEffect(()=>{
Dog.on("event1" function)


})

useEffect(()=>{
Dog.on("event2" function)


})
```

the reason behind this problem is sometime we are rfendering multiple time or trying to change a unmounted state